# GWT: How to disable the anchor link event when clicked

Tags: gwt

I want to disable the anchor link event when it clicked one time.  I used `anchor.setenabled(false)` but nothing happend.  When I click the same button again the event `e` is `true`.  I want `false` at that time.

```
public void onCellClick(GridPanel grid, int rowIndex, int colindex,EventObject e) 
    {
                    if(rowIndex==0 && colindex==2){
                        tomcatHandler = "Start";
                        anchorStart.setEnabled(false);
                    }else if(rowIndex==0 && colindex==3){
                        tomcatHandler = "Stop";
                        ****anchorStop.setEnabled(false);
                        anchorStart.setEnabled(false);
                        anchorRestart.setEnabled(true);****

                }else if(rowIndex==0 &&colindex==4){
                    tomcatHandler = "Restart";
                    anchorRestart.setEnabled(false);
                }

                    AdminService.Util.getInstance().tomcat(tomcatHandler,new AsyncCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String result) {
                            imageChangeEvent(result);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        }
                    });}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchors in GWT have always had a problem with `setEnabled()` because HTML doesn't support such a property. A quick workaround is to create a new widget that subclasses GWT's `Anchor`, adding the following override:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
        case Event.ONDBLCLICK:
        case Event.ONFOCUS:
        case Event.ONCLICK:
            if (!isEnabled()) {
                return;
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
}
```

This disables the passing of the browser event to GWT's `Anchor` class (summarily disabling all related handlers) when the link is double clicked, focused or clicked and is in a disabled state.

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2889)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to actually disable the anchor, but it does retain the status that has been set with anchor.setEnabled(), so just test that within your handler e.g.

```
    myAnchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent evt) {
            // write to filter and then call reload
            if (((Anchor) evt.getSource()).isEnabled()) {
               //do stuff
            }
        }

    });
```